# PayPal iOS MECL getInstance method crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, paypal

I am using Paypal-sdk for my Application but on trying following code

```
[[PayPal getInstance] fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID:@"APP-<app id>" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX withDelegate:self];
```

Following crash occurs:

```
+[PayPal getInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x430588
```

Please help in identifying problem..
Thanks.

Comment: did you use `[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];` code to intilize paypal.??

Comment: @RahulPatel actually when i tried to use this method xcode did not recognize it as a known method.  :(

Comment: Check Paypal.h to see if getInstance is declared there. If its class method or instance method.

Comment: It is class method and it is already declared in PayPal.h file..

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this problem is solved.
Actually I was using old sdk with ios5 which is not compatible for ios 5 version.
I changed the sdk and everything runs fine now..

thanks for your support..